# При запуске autofs main process terminated with status 1

Tags: ubuntu

После ребута не примантируются папки прописанные в `/etc/auto.server`

После выполнения `sudo restart autofs`, папки примантируются.

В `/var/log/syslog:`

```
init: autofs main process (756) terminated with status 1
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux 3.2.0-64-generic-pae #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 22:22:15 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

В `/etc/default/nfs-common` ставил `NEED_STATD=yes`. Не помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте монтировать файловую систему не через autofs, а через fstab

Comment: @ВикторРэд Требуется использовать именно autofs. Имеется несколько десятков машин, везде работает нормально, а на одной наблюдается вышеописанная проблема. 
Какая дополнительная информация поможет в диагностике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил добавлением в `/etc/rc.local` строчки:
`/etc/init.d/autofs restart`

Напишите, пожалуйста, если у кого есть лучшее решение.